# Finding similarity words and changing them

Tags: r, similarity

I have a dataset which containing text variable, I have there mistakes written by people for example it should be cat, and is cay. I've changed it manually, but I'm searching for solutions, how to do it quicker.

```
mutate(word = gsub("(.*)ca(?!)*(.*)", "cat", word, perl = T))
```

Comment: check the package hunspell. But incorrect spelling is a difficult solution to automate.

Comment: Not sure it's best in your case but I often use chains of unix `sed` commands to correct spelling when text-mining. It can be faster than building complex regex.

Answer (score 1):

You did not provide any context, but if you have an idea which words could be misspelled you could use a string distance metric to determine which inputs are potentially misspelled:

```
library(stringdist)
text <- c("sentence with a cat", 
          "sentence with a cay", 
          "sentence with a ced", 
          "sentence with a cta")
sapply(strsplit(text, " "), # split into words
       # use minimum distance in the words
       # stringdist recycles "cat" for each word in the sentence
       function(sentence) min(stringdist(sentence, "cat")))
# [1] 0 1 2 1
```

This tells you that in sentence 1 `cat` occurs as such, in sentence 2 there is a word which needs 1 insertion/deletion/swap to reach the word `cat`, in sentence 3 you need already 2 of these operations and in sentence 4 you need 1 (a swap). With this approach you could at least filter/sort the text according to similarity  to your search terms. However, you will need an idea of which words are potentially misspelled.